# Python 3.4 pickle.load() don't work

Tags: python, pickle

EDITED
My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os.path
import pickle

def read_hts(hts):
    if(os.path.isfile("hts.pickle")):
        p = open("hts.pickle", "rb")
        hts = pickle.load(p)
        p.close()
    else:
        f = open("hts.dat", "r")
        for line in f:
        spl = line.split()
        val = [spl[2], spl[3], spl[4]]
        hts[spl[0]+"."+spl[1]] = val
    f.close()
    p = open("hts.pickle", "wb")
    pickle.dump(hts, p)
    p.close()

def main():
    hts = {}
    read_hts(hts)
    print(list(hts))

main()
```

The hts.dat file:

```
1 A1 1 1 6523.00
1 A2 1 2 10823.08
1 A3 1 3 8661.76
1 A4 1 4 9851.96
1 A5 1 5 6701.12
1 A6 1 6 12934.13
1 A7 1 7 11882.38
1 A8 1 8 9787.36
1 A9 1 9 10292.06
1 A10 1 10 9040.32
1 A11 1 11 12742.89
1 A12 1 12 11607.01
1 A13 1 13 13638.06
1 A14 1 14 11038.11
1 A15 1 15 11839.42
1 A16 1 16 13206.73
```

If there is no hts.pickle the output is:

```
['1.A3',  '1.A7', '1.A14', '1.A11', '1.A8', '1.A16', '1.A15', '1.A12', '1.A9', '1.A4', '1.A1', '1.A6', '1.A10', '1.A2', '1.A5', '1.A13']
```

But if there is a hts.pickle the output is only:

```
[]
```

I don't understand why it don't restores the dictonary. EDIT: I think pickle is not the problem. It have to be a problem with the variables.

Comment: The first time (dumping) it is running fine but all furher calls I get an empty list. I use python 3.4

Comment: Still cannot reproduce. cannot you try printing `hts` inside the if loop . And I am hoping you are correctly importing both `os.path` and `pickle` at the start?

Comment: I edited my code. I think it is a problem with the variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with the pickle , when your pickle file already exists , it is creating a completely new dictionary object and returning and your are assigning this back to hts variable , this will not change the hts variable in your main() function .

In the else part you are changing the hts variable inplace hence it will reflect in the main() function.

Instead of relying on this , you should always return the variable hts from your function , and assign it back to hts in your main() function.